# Pin not showing on Mapkit - obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm a newbie to ios dev. I tried to add pin annotations on map using mapkit. However, after tried the most basic methods, it still didn't show up, either that's a simple pin, or a custom annotationview. There is no error message, it's just the pin won't show up in the map.
Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Custom Annotations start.");
    // Custom Annotations.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bryanParkCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.785834, -122.406417);
    MyCustomAnnotation *bryanParkAnnotation = [[MyCustomAnnotation alloc]initWithTitle:@"Bryant Park" Location:bryanParkCoordinates];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:bryanParkAnnotation];

    // Simple pin.
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:bryanParkCoordinates];
    [annotation setTitle:@"Title"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    // Another try.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.330713, -121.894348);
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

    MKPointAnnotation *newannotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [newannotation setCoordinate:coord];

    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    // On your location.
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = bryanParkCoordinates;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyCustomAnnotation class]])
    {
        MyCustomAnnotation *myLocation = (MyCustomAnnotation *)annotation;
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomAnnotation"];
        if(annotationView == nil)
            annotationView = myLocation.annotationView;
        else
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        return annotationView;
    }
    else{
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"DETAILPIN_ID"];
        [pinView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
        [pinView setCanShowCallout:NO];
        return pinView;
}
}
```

If I just want a simple pin on map, just adding those lines

```
// Simple pin.
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    [annotation setCoordinate:bryanParkCoordinates];
    [annotation setTitle:@"Title"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

should be enough? Is there other things that I could have missed? Like adding other delegate or something else other than adding those simple codes in 'viewDidLoad'? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Managing Annotation Views

You should implement this delegate method and create a view for the annotation and return it.

basically when you add an annotation this delegates method will get called and you have to create the view for that annotation within this delegate method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"Custom Annotations start.");
    // Custom Annotations.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bryanParkCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.785834, -122.406417);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.330713, -121.894348);
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.1, 0.1);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

    [self.mapView setRegion:region];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = bryanParkCoordinates;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a short example of how this function will be like for the simple MKPointAnnotation? Sincerely appreciate it!

Comment: So this function is called in the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: no . thisis a MKMapViewDelegate method . You need to first confirm to the delegate.  then implement the method.  one thing you need to understand is  what you have added now is an MKPointAnnotation and what you want to see on the map is  MKAnnotationView. both are different  . annottation is a datasource with which you need to create  a  MKAnnotationView which is a subclass of UIView

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code, added the '(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation' method, is that the one you are talking about? But this one still didn't work

Comment: just try out this link . [link](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/simple-mapview-tutorial-in-swift-mapkit.html)

Comment: Thanks, but sorry I'm still confused, I didn't see it added any MKMapViewDelegate - like method, it only added the annotation, and it's in swift.. sorry.. But I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: @Qiaofei. can you check my updated code. just ignore the delegate case  simply add this in your viewdidload method

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code, it still didn't show up, but now I think the problem is the whole mapview didn't update any changes that I made in the code. Because I disabled the location manager, but the user location is still showing up in the map. Do you know any possible reason that the whole mapview still stays in the original situation? Thanks!

Comment: Also I notice there is an error in console: Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) return nil;

    static NSString* Identifier = @"PinAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView;
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:Identifier];

    if (pinView == nil) {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                  reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        return pinView;
    }
    pinView.annotation = annotation;
    return pinView;
}
```

Don't forget to add `<MKMapViewDelegate>` to your `@interface` section.

```
@interface YourViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Thanks Kosuke! Thanks, I added the Delegate method and updated mine using your code, it still didn't show up, but now I think the problem is the whole mapview didn't update any changes that I made in the code. Because I disabled the location manager, but the user location is still showing up in the map. Do you know any possible reason that the whole mapview still stays in the original situation? Thanks!

Comment: Also I notice there is an error in console: Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4